# ScrollIntoView doesn't smooth on mobile (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll

I created a sample scrollIntoView in an Angular project. It works great on web browser. However, when you view it on mobile (Chrome or Safari), the behaviour is flaky. It jumps right to the position without "smooth" behaviour.

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="scroll('one')">One</button>
<button (click)="scroll('two')">Two</button>
<button (click)="scroll('three')">Three</button>
<button (click)="scroll('four')">Four</button>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Mobile scrollIntoView';

  scroll(id: string) {
    console.log(`scrolling to ${id}`);
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});
  }
}
```

You can view it on stackblitz - open with your phone: https://angular-nbpxk7.stackblitz.io

Edit mode: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbpxk7

Am I missing something or how can I archive the "smooth" behaviour on mobile? Thanks,

Comment: You're not missing anything. Just because scrollIntoView not support `smooth` behavior on iOS Safari. https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Comment: Thanks Toan. Are there any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not seem a problem with angular but rather a [cross-browser compatibility issue](https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview). The smooth property does not work in almost all mobile devices (except chrome and firefox for android.

In [here](https://medium.com/@snowleo208/how-to-create-smooth-scroll-for-your-website-ce5b198d9d94) you have an alternative, but you need to build your custom implementation of the smooth scrollIntoView.

For doing that, I prepare a custom function which you can find a full working example in [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjzwqh?file=src/app/app.component.ts) based on your code. For those you want to use it on an angular base application, you just need to add the following function to your component, and call it by passing the desire dom element:

```
scrollCustomImplementation(element: HTMLElement) {
    let start = null;
    let target = element && element ? element.getBoundingClientRect().top : 0;
    let firstPos = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    let pos = 0;

    (function () {
      var browser = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];

      for (var x = 0, length = browser.length; x < length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; x++) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[browser[x] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[browser[x] + 'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[browser[x] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
      }
    })();

    function showAnimation(timestamp) {
      if (!start) {
        start = timestamp || new Date().getTime();
      } //get id of animation


      var elapsed = timestamp - start;
      var progress = elapsed / 600; // animation duration 600ms
      //ease in function from https://github.com/component/ease/blob/master/index.js

      var outQuad = function outQuad(n) {
        return n * (2 - n);
      };

      var easeInPercentage = +outQuad(progress).toFixed(2); // if target is 0 (back to top), the position is: current pos + (current pos * percentage of duration)
      // if target > 0 (not back to top), the positon is current pos + (target pos * percentage of duration)

      pos = target === 0 ? firstPos - firstPos * easeInPercentage : firstPos + target * easeInPercentage;
      window.scrollTo(0, pos);
      console.log(pos, target, firstPos, progress);

      if (target !== 0 && pos >= firstPos + target || target === 0 && pos <= 0) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(start);

        if (element) {
          element.setAttribute("tabindex", -1);
          element.focus();
        }

        pos = 0;
      } else {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(showAnimation);
      }
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(showAnimation);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. I tried your link on safari and it actually works!

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I figured out the scrolling down is smooth. However, scrolling up is weird. Can you help to talk a look? Thanks,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nbpxk7